# How wp maps urls into files

Tags: loop, customization, permalinks, shortcode

I am trying to understand how wordpress works. I have found this line of code in my theme:

```
<?php echo get_permalink(get_option('Theme_search_page_id')) ?>
```

If I get the that option from mysql I recive:

```
mysql> select * from wp_options where option_name='Theme_search_page_id';
+-----------+---------------------------------+--------------+----------+
| option_id | option_name                     | option_value | autoload |
+-----------+---------------------------------+--------------+----------+
|       164 |            Theme_search_page_id | 12           | yes      |
+-----------+---------------------------------+--------------+----------+
```

The permalink with `id=12` is `http://localhost/wordpress/service-search/`. If I click in this last url present in my theme, wordpress call a file `lib/search.php`. My question is, how wordpress know which file to call and where this file is located?

Answer (score -2):

Go to "Pages" and find the page with the ID. Open it in editor. On the right hand side, look for "page attributes". You can add php files here. All you have to do is, create a PHP page under your theme, and add this to your beginning of the file:

```
<?php
/*
 Template Name: A PAGE NAME HERE
 */
```

Reload, and your file shows up with the `A PAGE NAME HERE` within the select box.